# How to use remote kendo Datasource as filter for Kendo Scheduler

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I can see from kendo's own demo (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index), that you can use checkboxes to filter people. I am looking to do a similar thing but I have a separate remote kendo datasource that pulls "reps." These reps are represented in a drop down on my custom editor for the scheduler widget, but I want to be able to filter by my datasource. Can can you do this with a kendo DS that's pulling remote data and not hard coded values like they show?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Show us what you got

Comment: I actually ended up figuring it out. I'll post an answer with details. Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out using another bit of HTML on the page with the scheduler.

Something like this...

```
 <!-- template for table -->
        <script id="event-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
            <div class="schedule-template">
                <p>#: title #</p>

                <p>#: rep #</p>
            </div>
        </script>
```

Then in your JS, something to the effect of this...

```
    $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    date: new Date(),
    startTime: new Date("2015/9/13 07:00 AM"),
    endTime: new Date("2015/9/13 17:00"),
    height: 700,
    editable: {
        destroy: false,
        template: $("#editor").html(),
        window: {
            title: "Auction",
            width: 700
        }
    },
    eventTemplate: $("#event-template").html(),
    timezone: "Etc/UTC",
```

Note, the eventTemplate line